# Arduino interfacing graphically

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Is there a way to show a sensor output in monitor as some pictorial representation using arduino ?? Like if sensor is high i need green bar to show in monitor or is there any interfacing software to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Arduino IDE, the information you're extracting from the ATmega 328P is via Serial. Somehow, it is like using the command console from your computer and it won't let you do what you really want. But you can use python to make a Graphical User Interface that receive all the information from the Arduino using pySerial library.

Please read [this instructive](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/41509) made by LetsMakeRobots, it's complete and easy to understand.